# Insulating townhouse's attic sidewall?

Tags: insulation, roof, attic

Last winter, I've had some issues with ice dams on my roof. I live in a townhouse in Southern Quebec, Canada, in the middle unit, where lately temperatures during the winter can go anywhere between -40C to 10C.

So this year, I've decided to go look in the attic. There was a lot of insulation missing near the eaves and the space was pretty warm. I spent an afternoon in there filling the gaps, and insulating some exhaust pipes that needed it. I managed to drop the temperature by a good 7 or 8 degrees Celcius, so I figured it would be enough.

Today, it's about -7C and cloudy with a bit of snow. I went to double-check that my changes were good. I found that sure enough, the temperature has dropped below freezing for the most part (figure #1). However, both the sidewalls - made of brick - are still pretty warm (figures #2 and #3).

[image]
(Figure #1, attic temp)

[image]
[image]
(Figure #2 and #3, attic sidewalls temp)

So my first question is, I'm assuming that both my neighbors have similar insulation issues in their attics and that their warm air is leaking in my attic, am I right?

Assuming that's the case, and that I cannot get either or both of them to fix the issue on their end, is there anything I can do on my end, and should I? If so, what is it and how much work would that be?